# Regular expression that checks for 1-10 in increments of .5?

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a regular expression that only allows user input within the range of 1-10
and only in increments of .5

Basically only 1 - 1.5 - 2 - 2.5 - 3 - 3.5 - 4 - 4.5 - 5... 9.5 - 10  would be allowed

I would try and use another way to do this, but in this case I have to use a regular expression in my program.

So far I have tried this:

```
"^[1-10](.5)?$"
```

and also this:

```
"^[1-9](.5)?[10]$"
```

and this:

```
"^[1-9](.5)?|[10]$"
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
"^[1-9](\\.5)?|10$"
```

- `.` should be escaped to literally match a dot.
- Backslash itself should be escaped. (It's a java string literal).

Answer (score 2):

```
10|[1-9](?:\.5)?
```

Either `10`, or a digit from `1` to `9` optionally followed by `.5`.

Enclose between `^...$` if you want it to reject substring matches.

(Given that it's Java, remember to escape the backslash in strings!)

Comment: @Julius: Why would I want to capture only .5? The whole number is already captured as the whole match here. I generally use (?:...) unless I specifically want to capture something. It's a habit that helps when you're writing complex regular expressions, and it's a pain to see if the thing that you really want is `\7` or `\8`.

Comment: and just surround with () and repeat the pattern if you want to capture the whole thing more than once

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>() {
        {
            add(1.0);
            add(1.5);
            add(2.5);
            add(9.5);
            add(2.3);
            add(7.1);
            add(10.0);
        }
    };

    for (Double value : list) {
        if (value % 1 == 0 || (value - 0.5) % 1 == 0) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1.0
1.5
2.5
9.5
10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close. Consider the following minor change to your regex...

```
^[1-9](\.5)?$|^10$
```

G0od Luck!